# PHP - Oracle connection error - Database error: Link-ID == false (), oci_connect failed

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

I have my PHP Oracle successful setup.
When I run simple script with `oci_connect()`, `oci_parse()`, and run query to get single row or any data from oracle, I gets data correctly.

However, when I have `db_oci8.inc` in my project, when I'm working in my project with PHP - Oracle connection, it throws error always as below :

```
Database error: Link-ID == false (), oci_connect failed
ORACLE Error: 
Session halted.
```

Sample code when I get data correctly :

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('user', 'pass', 'localhost/XE');

if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM usernm where ID=186');
oci_execute($stid);
echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
?>
```

Comment: Make sure your failing code is showing the full Oracle error message.

Comment: @ChristopherJones The only error I got is as above.

Comment: That looks more like a framework or custom library error. You might need to add some more tracing code or use a debugger to see what's going on.